# Dask distributed does not run SVD if some of the chunks contain only NaN values

Tags: dask, svd, dask-distributed

First of all thank you for providing dask with all its functionality, which is highly appreciated!

However, using `dask.distributed` to run an SVD on a rasterized dataset, it seems as if it fails when only single chunks consist only of NaN values although most of the dataset does contain correct values.

I read a dataset using `xarray.open_mfdataset(chunks={...})` and try to set the chunksize such, that SVD computation (`dask.array.linalg`) used in the [eofs.xarray](https://ajdawson.github.io/eofs/latest/api/eofs.xarray.html#module-eofs.xarray) package makes use of the cores our cluster provides, by using a `dask.distributed` client.

```sh
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (time: 8760, x: 1000, y: 840)
Coordinates:
  * x         (x) float64 2.452e+06 2.458e+06 2.462e+06 ... 7.442e+06 7.448e+06
  * y         (y) float64 1.352e+06 1.358e+06 1.362e+06 ... 5.542e+06 5.548e+06
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2005-01-01 ... 2005-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    capacity  (y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(840, 1000), chunksize=(840, 840)>
    capfac    (time, y, x) float32 dask.array<shape=(8760, 840, 1000), chunksize=(876, 840, 840)>
```

However, when I run the computation, it fails with the below-mentioned error message.

```sh
ValueError: error encountered in SVD, check that missing values are in the same places at each time and that all the values are not missing
```

See complete error message:

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.conda/envs/spagat_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eofs/standard.py in __init__(self, dataset, weights, center, ddof)
    164                 # Use the parallel Dask algorithm
--> 165                 dsvd = dask.array.linalg.svd(dataNoMissing)
    166                 A, Lh, E = (x.compute() for x in dsvd)

~/.conda/envs/spagat_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/linalg.py in svd(a)
    803     """
--> 804     return tsqr(a, compute_svd=True)
    805 

~/.conda/envs/spagat_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/array/linalg.py in tsqr(data, compute_svd, _max_vchunk_size)
    116             "Current shape: {},\nCurrent chunksize: {}".format(
--> 117                 data.shape, data.chunksize
    118             )

ValueError: Input must have the following properties:
  1. Have two dimensions
  2. Have only one column of blocks

Note: This function (tsqr) supports QR decomposition in the case of
tall-and-skinny matrices (single column chunk/block; see qr)Current shape: (8760, nan),
Current chunksize: (876, nan)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f60250fedf8b> in <module>
----> 1 pca.analyze()

~/code/tsa_lib/tsa_lib/time_tools.py in f(*args, **kwargs)
      8     def f(*args, **kwargs):
      9         before = time.perf_counter()  # maybe exchange with time.process_time()
---> 10         rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
     11         after = time.perf_counter()
     12         print('elapsed time for {.__name__}: {:.2f} minutes'.format(func, (after - before)/60))

~/code/playground/playground/PCA.py in analyze(self)
    145             print('PCA completed. Weights used.')
    146         else:
--> 147             self.eofs, self.pcs, self.solver = eof_analysis(self.data_variability, n_eofs=None, xarray=True)
    148             print('PCA completed. No weights used.')
    149 

~/code/tsa_lib/tsa_lib/time_tools.py in f(*args, **kwargs)
      8     def f(*args, **kwargs):
      9         before = time.perf_counter()  # maybe exchange with time.process_time()
---> 10         rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
     11         after = time.perf_counter()
     12         print('elapsed time for {.__name__}: {:.2f} minutes'.format(func, (after - before)/60))

~/code/playground/playground/PCA.py in eof_analysis(data, n_eofs, xarray, wgts, lats)
     36             solver = xEof(data, weights=wgts)
     37         else:
---> 38             solver = xEof(data)
     39 
     40     eofs = solver.eofsAsCovariance(neofs=n_eofs)

~/.conda/envs/spagat_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eofs/xarray.py in __init__(self, array, weights, center, ddof)
    131                                     weights=wtarray,
    132                                     center=center,
--> 133                                     ddof=ddof)
    134         # Name of the input DataArray.
    135         self._name = array.name

~/.conda/envs/spagat_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eofs/standard.py in __init__(self, dataset, weights, center, ddof)
    175 
    176         except (np.linalg.LinAlgError, ValueError):
--> 177             raise ValueError('error encountered in SVD, check that missing '
    178                              'values are in the same places at each time and '
    179                              'that all the values are not missing')

ValueError: error encountered in SVD, check that missing values are in the same places at each time and that all the values are not missing
```

When applying SVD on a rasterized dataset, the below-mentioned error is given. Is it possible, that the error is raised because single chunks might be only containing NaN values?

If so, it could be considered as a bug of dask.distributed because the SVD works fine when applying it without chunking. Hence, the SVD should not fail only because single chunks only contain NaN values, whereas other chunks contain valid values, should it?

Comment: If you have found a but then I recommend raising an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

Comment: I created an [issue on dask's github page](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5368) as suggested, that was answered there.